# Define term using Stirling Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, stirling-numbers

I am trying to solve the following exercise - quite unsuccessful yet.

> Let *a(m,n)* be defined as 
>   $$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^m a(m,n) \prod\limits_{i=1}^n (x+i-1) = x^m $$ 
>   Express *a(m,n)* using *S(m,n)* while *S(m,n)* are the *Stirling numbers of the second kind* which count the number of ways to partition a set of n elements into k nonempty subsets.
>
> Hint: use the following identity : $$x^m = \sum\limits_{n=0}^m S(m,n) \cdot x \cdot (x-1) \cdots (x-n + 1) $$

First I rewrote the "hint"-identity as 
$$ x^m = \sum\limits_{n=0}^m S(m,n) \prod\limits_{i=1}^n (x+1-i)$$

and got
$$ m = 0 \rightarrow a(0,0) = x^0 = S(0,0) $$
$$ m = 1 \rightarrow a(1,0) + a(1,1) \cdot x = S(1,0) + S(1,1) \cdot x $$
and m = 2
$$ a(2,0) + a(2,1) \cdot x + a(2,2) \cdot x \cdot (x+1) = S(2,0) \cdot x + S(2,1) \cdot x + S(2,2) \cdot x \cdot (x-1)$$
and both compared for m = 3
$$ \begin{array}{llll} a(3,0) & + a(3,1) \cdot x & + a(3,2) \cdot x \cdot (x+1) & + a(3,3) \cdot x \cdot (x+1) \cdot (x+2) \\ \underbrace{S(3,0) \cdot x}_{\text{always 0}} & +S(3,1) \cdot x & +S(3,2) \cdot x \cdot (x-1) & +S(3,3) \cdot x \cdot (x-1) \cdot (x-2) \end{array} 
 $$

Replacing *x* with *-x* in the "hint"-identity as recommended by user9325 results in

$$ \begin{array}{llll} a(3,0) & + a(3,1) \cdot x & + a(3,2) \cdot x \cdot (x+1) & + a(3,3) \cdot x \cdot (x+1) \cdot (x+2) \\ S(3,0) & +S(3,1) \cdot (-x) & +S(3,2) \cdot (-x) \cdot (-x-1) & +S(3,3) \cdot (-x)(-x-1)(-x-2) \end{array} $$

Multiplying each summand of the already modified identity by $(-1)^{(n+1)}$ gets

$$ \begin{array}{llll} a(3,0) & + a(3,1) \cdot x & + a(3,2) \cdot x \cdot (x+1) & + a(3,3) \cdot x \cdot (x+1) \cdot (x+2) \\ S(3,0) & +S(3,1) \cdot x & +S(3,2) \cdot x \cdot (x+1) & +S(3,3) \cdot x\cdot(x+1)\cdot(x+2) \end{array} $$

Is this correct? How do I put this altogether?

Comment: Have you tried fiddling with $x$ in the second identity to get it to look more like the first identity?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? What should I do with the *x*?

Comment: What does it occur to you to do? Maybe you should write out both identities more explicitly, term-by-term, and see if something occurs to you.

Comment: I modified the original post according to this

Comment: @muffel: You calculations contain errors and it is quite unclear how you arrive at your conclusion.

Comment: You've got the case $m=1$ wrong to start with. What you should have is $\Sigma_{n=0}^m a(m,n) x^{\overline{n}} = \Sigma_{n=0}^m S(m,n) x^{\underline{n}}$

Comment: @user9325 This was just what I expected. I arrived at my conclusion by putting the terms containing "S(m,n)" just below the ones containing the "a(m,n)" ones. After doing that I saw that (except from the first term which is always 0) both terms look the same. Could you please tell me what my errors are?

Comment: Please check the case $m=1$ first. You *should* try to find your errors to practice, but the problem I see that you decided that "terms look the same" that are not the same. But for solving the actual question, I propose that you start by rewriting your general equation in a way that both sides use the product symbol or neither side uses it.

Comment: @user9325 OK, I found (hopefully all of) them and corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest way to find the answer is to replace $x$ by $-x$ in one of the identities and then compare them.

Comment: Using this for the Stirling Numbers Identity I get for m = 3 S(3,0) + S(3,1)(-x) + S(3,2)(-x)(-1-x) + S(3,3)(-x)(-1-x)(-2-x) = a(3,0) + a(3,1) x + a(3,2) x (-1+x) + a(3,3) x (-1+x) (-2+x). Now the terms look more like each other, but the sign of x still differs. I don't see any way getting this switched.. Any further hint?

Comment: @muffel Collect the signs in front of each summand.

Comment: well, replacing x by (-x) and multiplying each summand by (-1) gets what I want. But the last part is still a mystery for me: What can I use to define a(m,n)? Just using "a(m,n) = S(m,n) * (-1)" won't change x to (-x) as no factor would at all. So what "trick" do I need here?

Comment: @muffel: You don't need a trick and $(-1)$ is not the right factor. Write it out in detail.

Comment: I added this to the original question. Why is (-1) not the right factor? $(-1)\cdot S(3,3)(-x)(-x-1)(-x-2)=S(3,3)\cdot x \cdot (x+1)(x+2)$ and this is what I want, or am I missing something?

Comment: This is just one case, not the general case.

Comment: Of course, you were right. It's $(-1)^{(n+1)}$ which I have to multiply all summands with. But I still have the problem that I replaced x by (-x). So setting "a(n,m) = (-1)^{(n+1)}$" is not enough. How do I add the part concerning the "-x"?

Comment: @muffel: What happens to the other side of the equation when you replace $x$ by $-x$?

Comment: ok, what about $a(m,n) = S(m,n) \cdot (-1)^{(n+m)}$? this should cover both, the inverted x and the conversion by (-1).

Comment: @muffel: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: great, thank you very much for your help and patience!

Comment: @muffel: You are welcome.